# Limit of two variables function.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to find limit of the function (The limit should be "1"):
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (-1,0)} \frac{x^2y - xy^2 + xy - 2x + 2y - 2}{x^2 - y^2 + 2y - 1} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (-1,0)} \frac{xy(x-y + 1) - 2(x - y + 1)}{(x - y)(x+y) + 2y - 1} = 
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (-1,0)} \frac{(xy - 2)(x-y+1)}{(x - y)(x+y) + 2y - 1}$$

But I can't find way to reduce the organ in the denominator that cause zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (-1,0)} \frac{x^2y - xy^2 + xy - 2x + 2y - 2}{x^2 - y^2 + 2y - 1} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (-1,0)} \frac{xy(x-y + 1) - 2(x - y + 1)}{(x-y+1)(x+y-1)} = 
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (-1,0)} \frac{(xy - 2)}{(x+y-1)} = 1$$

Comment: Thank you, but what helped you to understand that: x^2−y^2+2^y−1 = (x−y+1)(x+y−1)?

Comment: I thought the limit was easy so the denominator has to be one of the factor on the denominator. The denominator obviously can't be $xy-2$, so I tried $(x-y+1)$ and it worked.